# PI with red jacket in a parallel dimension

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

Around the year 2000, there was an animated series about a private investigator / detective being sucked into a parallel dimension. Of what I remember, he went there through a portal and the world he landed on was mostly desert.

IIRC, he was wearing black trousers and shirt and a red jacket and had black hair. He had a friend with him, I think somebody that was ported with him.

In one episode, they had to go through a giant maze with different perils and at some time, there where guardians on flying discs and with energy weapons. His objective was to find a way back to earth and free the world from those guardians. I think to remember that his name was John or Jack, but am very unsure of it.

The show was displayed on KinderKanal (KiKa) sometime around 17:00. I've checked [here](https://www.fernsehserien.de/serien-nach-sendern/kika/2000) and [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_KiKA-Sendungen) if I was able to find it but can't find anything.

Comment: Was the series German language?

Comment: The one I watched yes. But it didn't seem to be German production, it more appeared to be American.

Comment: Are you sure it's not from the Lupin storyline?

Comment: @rigacrypto yes. It was way 'edgier', as i remember it. The features where straigther, not so round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. The series is *Bob Morane* and what I remembered was something between Episode 9 and 11. My error was, that the show was not on KiKa but *Super RTL*.